# Update existing list to match new list

Tags: javascript, jquery, synchronization, dom-manipulation

I have tree-like list that can be collapsed or expanded by the user

```
<ul>
  <li class="exp">  
    ...
  </li> 
  <li> 
    ...
  </li> 
</ul>
```

The content if this list is lazy loaded because it can be large, but also because it can change depending on what else the user does on the page.

The lazy loading is working fine, but updating it after removing/adding items to the list is a problem

The way I'm doing it now is like this:

```
var old_i = 0,
    new_v = [];

new_li.each(function(i, li){
  new_v.push(node.dataset.value);

  // new li at the end
  if(!old_li.get(old_i)){
    old_ul.append(li);
    return;
  }

  // existing li
  if(li.dataset.value == old_li.get(old_i).dataset.value){       
    old_i++;
    return;
  }

  // new li before the end
  $(li).insertBefore(old_li.get(old_i));          
}); 

// remove non-existing
old_i.each(function(idx, li){
  if(new_v.indexOf(li.dataset.value) < 0)
    $(li).remove();
});
```

But when I remove a li that comes before the last one, the last one gets duplicated. I think the issue is near insertBefore but I don't know what's causing it.

Another thing I have no clue how to do is re-sort old list to match the ordering of the new list.

I know that I can just replace the list to make things easier, but then I will loose the user expand-collapse state. And not just the state classes, but the content too, because the ajax response only returns what needs to be updated, which is the content of the active li (direct children). But the user can expand children or grandchildren of it, and the content of those would be lost on with a replace

Answer (score 0):

I think the duplicates get created something like below:

If your old list was: a,b,c,d, and newlist: a,c,d:
Your loop works fine with a.
But when your new list loop is at c, your `old_li.get()` returns b, triggering an `insertBefore`. oldlist is now a,c,b,c,d.
Next pass, newlist returns d, and `old_li.get()` returns c (old_i is not incremented). This triggers another `insertBefore`. oldlist is now a,d,c,b,c,d.

After your remove round, the c value is removed, leaving newlist being a,d,d,c,c.

As an alternative approach, I would suggest:

```
var old_v; // array with only value strings from old state
var new_v; // array with only value strings from new state
var updatedLength=0;

old_v.reverse().map((itemVal,i) => { 
  if (new_v.indexOf(itemVal) != -1) {
    // remove item (i) from the old_li in DOM
    // loop over old_v in reverse order so we don't mess up count
  } else {
    UpdatedLength++;
  }
}
new_v.map((itemVal, i) => {
  if (old_v.indexOf(itemVal) == -1) {
    if (i >= updatedLength) {
      // append item (i) from the new_li to DOM at the end
    } else {
      // insert item (i) before item at index updatedLength in DOM
    }
    updatedLength++;
  }
  return itemVal;
}
```

Hope this works!